# how to solve requests.exceptions.ConnectionError in get request - Python

Tags: python, python-requests

when i run **`get_word`** function, i will get this error:

> `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

```
import requests
    
base_url = "https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/"
    
def get_word(word: str):
    return requests.get(base_url + word)
```

<strike>Please Answer this problem!</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me after I added a `User-Agent` header

```
import requests

base_url = "https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/"

def get_word(word: str):
    return requests.get(base_url + word, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

response = get_word('apple')
print(response.text)
```

Comment: How did you find out you had to add this headers argument?

Comment: @AliAryaie Some server requires this header to authenticate yourself as a User.

Comment: I know that some requestو especially POST requests need headers, but why in this case do we need "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"?

Comment: @AliAryaie it's dependent on the server the request being sent to, some servers require this to provide some additional layers of security